# Similar category titles with minor changes

Tags: seo, keyword-stuffing

I have an eshop that has say a 100 categories. 50 of them are different types of products, say potatoes, tomatos etc. The other 50 are another classification of the same products (a different menu) that have titles like Greek organic potatoes, Greek organic tomatoes, and some are like Greek non-organic tomatoes, French organic tomatoes, etc.

Is the repetition of "Greek organic" in front of most of those 50 categories a bad thing for a seo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not think so. Not in this case. I am assuming that there are only a moderate number of Greek and French categories etc. I would be careful and make sure that you are listing enough products to look like an honest retailer.

The general rule is, create an honest site for humans and you should be okay. If nearly all of your categories were Greek organic *something* then I would advise against it. However, it looks like you will likely have a good ratio of standard, Greek, French, and whatever other organic categories to remain reasonable. And that is the name of the game. Being reasonable.